# Sonar 5.1 Issues list - How to group by Issue Type

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

How can we identify the most common types of issues in a project in our current code base.

We have recently upgraded from Sonar 4.5 to 5.1

In 4.5 we used to view the issues list in a specific project, and the issues were grouped by issue type. For instance in one project the rule "Use a logger to log this exception" might be the most common critical rule with 45 violations. We could then use that information to drive improvement efforts.

In 5.1 we are now presented with a long list of issues with no apparent way of group them.

The ability to see what type of violation was most common was also useful in allowing us to see where best to direct our efforts in terms of remedial action.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do that easily on issue page of your project : just click on the rule facet and you should have the list of most violated rules.

See http://nemo.sonarqube.org/issues/search#resolved=false|projectUuids=b38e4f29-df5f-491e-9118-a0a4f5cda406 for instance and click on "Rule" facet.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed.

Comment: Is there a way to see **all** the issues grouped by rule?

Comment: Go to the issue page and use the rule facet

Comment: I'm finding that the UI only displays the first 15 rules that were violated. Is there a way to get it to display all of them?

Comment: Broken link on 4th link of answer

Answer (score 1):

To group issues by type you can use the rule facet in the web interface.

But you will have only the 15 more frequent rule violations.

Another possibility, is to use the web api directly with a comma separated list of the rules you are interested in.

```
GET http://localhost:9000/api/issues/search?rules=squid:S1905,squid:UndocumentedApi
```

Another solution, if you really want this feature is to customize Sonarqube by changing:

```
private static final int DEFAULT_FACET_SIZE = 15;
```

in [StickyFacetBuilder.java](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/server/sonar-server-common/src/main/java/org/sonar/server/es/StickyFacetBuilder.java)

You can also suggest a new feature here: https://community.sonarsource.com/c/suggestions

Answer (score -1):

There is a **Rule** filter on Issues tab.

Comment: down-voting because that could be said in comment and there it would be more appropriate.