# Sonar 5.6 Issues list - How to group by Issue Type all Issues

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

In Sonar I would like grouping by violated rule all Issues for one project  (I use the 5.6 version).
The expected result is that violated rules are all listed with their count and ordered by most frequent violation :

```
rule XXA : 50
rule XXB : 42
rule XXC : 30
.
.
.
rule XXX : 3
rule XXY : 1
```

When I tried to do that, I get only the most frequently violated rules and not all violated rules. It is rather annoying to not have a real overview of violated rules of a project. Drilling down in each project to identify all issues is clumsy and time-consuming.

I found that post [Sonar 5.1 Issues list - How to group by Issue Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32129176/sonar-5-1-issues-list-how-to-group-by-issue-type) but as someone indicated in the comment of the accepted answer :
"I'm finding that the UI only displays the first 15 rules that were violated. Is there a way to get it to display all of them?"

I know it is possible to have a complete overview of issue by issue types because I have already seen it on my screen but I don't remember what is the manipulation to do to get that.

Comment: Are you trying to see a list of all violated rules? Or a breakdown by the 3 issue _types_ (which is available by default)? Perhaps you could [edit] your question to clarify?

Comment: I edited  my answer with a concrete example.

Answer (score 1):

What you're remembering is from a rather old version of SonarQube. There is no way to get the full list of violated issues in more recent versions.

Comment: It is a pity since It is a very useful feature. When I do audit code for projects, I used that feature to have an overview.